# Rename the Built-In Directory Shortcuts in Thunar

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, shortcuts, thunar

Is there a way to rename the built-in shortcuts in Thunar? In particular, I'm interested in renaming these:

[image]

Unfortunately, the rename option doesn't appear on right-click like it does for any directory shortcuts I create myself.

Comment: Might be a good question for the Thunar project team. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/thunar#Tips_and_tricks

Comment: Maybe remove the default shortcuts, and replace them with your own, pointing to the same locations?

Comment: I can't remove the default shortcuts. There's no "remove" option when I right-click on the ones in the image.

Comment: Ah, but I can see that I can hide them by right-clicking in an empty space in the sidebar. So that's something I can work with, at least.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the default location Thunar opens to by changing the shortcut / command from:

`exo-open --launch FileManager &u`

to

`exo-open --launch FileManager /`

That will make it open at the root of the filesystem instead of in the current user's profile (i.e., `/home/username`).